# Are the folders /opt/mqm/properties/version/ and /opt/mqm/maintenance/8.0.0.6/MQSeriesFTAgent/backup/opt/mqm/properties/version safe to be deleted?

Tags: ibm-mq

Can you please confirm if the folders /opt/mqm/properties/**version**, /opt/mqm/maintenance/8.0.0.6/**MQSeriesFTAgent/backup/opt/mqm/properties/version** and /opt/mqm/maintenance/8.0.0.6/**MQSeriesFTService/backup/opt/mqm/properties/version** can be deleted.

Comment: The maintenance directories are required to uninstall that fix pack.  They will build up if you install multiple fix packs over time, you can prevent this by uninstalling all but the base version and then applying the latest fix pack.   If you needed to back out you would need to uninstall the new fix pack and reinstall the prior version.

Comment: @JoshMc: Thanks for the inputs on maintenance directory. Any suggestions on directory /opt/mqm/properties/version

Comment: Not specifically sure but looks similar.  In general nothing under /opt/mqm should be touched.

Comment: @JoshMc : Thank you for the inputs